# Youtube plays a video when my phone is locked and when it should not be playing anything

Tags: chrome-for-android, firefox-for-android

On my Samsung 20 FE 5G I'm getting a bad problem with YouTube on a browser. If I watch a video and it ends you get the standard auto play next video in 10 seconds. If I click on the youtube icon, to stop the autoplay, then close down the phone, after ~10 seconds, I'll hear a video has started to play. This is annoying as it can catch me out where I browsed away, closed the phone and expect it to be silent rather than start blaring sound.

Is there any way to disable this behaviour? It seems like a bad enough bug. I see it in both the Chrome and Firefox browsers.

**Update**

Just experimenting, if I browse to the end of a video, see the 10 second autoplay, and close the browser (i.e. With the home button), then after ~10 seconds it's start playing the next video. The audio does not stop which it normal would when the browser is not in focus. This only happens with the ~10 second play next video, if I close the browser while playing a video then the sound stops.

Comment: You could close the browser app. And this has nothing to do with android. Autoplay exists on windows desktop too. And requires several presses to stop.  I suspect the culprit is javascript.

Comment: I havent flagged it as off topic because there may be an Android only solution.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. If the autoplay is not needed, then I believe you can turn it off by toggling the switch on the video. As for the video keeps playing, it looks like you're playing a playlist which is then queued and can be played in the background while browsing the other sections of YouTube. In that case, I believe you have to press "Cancel" rather than tapping the YouTube icon.

Comment: AndrewT. I see no option to turn it off. @Rohit Gupta I have not seen this on my desktop. It may exist on iOS but I've no way to test it. It seems like strange behaviour for Android as normally when you close the browse it stops all activity. In this case, even when I "exit" out of the browse, this behaviour still occurs. Note: By close I mean using the home button.

Comment: @ShaneGannon does [this switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvuRZ.jpg) not appear when tapping the video on the browser?

Comment: @AndrewT. Thank you. I expected an option like that on the first screen. But it shows after pressing cancel.